# Limiting an OVER statement in Spotfire

Tags: spotfire

I am creating a line chart where X=Month Y=Unique Count of Reference Numbers (coloured by the status of the Reference Number), showing the variance from the previous month.  However, there is a huge spike for the first month on the chart, as this is the first instance of the data.  Is there a way to limit the expression to exclude the first month?

I'm currently using this custom expression:

```
UniqueCount([Opportunity #]) - UniqueCount([Opportunity #]) OVER (PreviousPeriod([Axis.X]))
```

Answer (score 0):

Best thing would be to just limit the underlying data...

- Right Click > Edit > Visulization Properties
- Go to the Data page
- Click **Edit** next to the Limit data using expression section
- Use an expression like `[DateColumn] > Date(2017,01,31)` which would exclude all data prior to Feb 1.

Otherwise, you'd want an `IF()` statement, likely in the latter part of your expression.

```
UniqueCount([Opportunity #]) - if([DateColumn] >= Date(2017,02,01),UniqueCount([Opportunity #]) OVER (PreviousPeriod([Axis.X])))
```

Comment: Thanks, but unfortunately neither of those solutions work.  The Limit Data expression has no effect - and the IF() statement within the custom expression returns a request "please specify an aggregation method".  It's really strange - as I have a 2nd graph using the same data set, but is showing a variance of the Sum(Value) of each Opportunity # - and that works fine, but it doesn't work for the UniqueCount of Opp #.

Comment: Limiting the data has to have some effect even if it is t your desired effect. Can you post a sample data set and image of the graph

Comment: I'll try and get a sample together, but using the limit expression either has no effect, or just shift the starting point of the graph.

For example, my first date is 01-Aug-16, so when I set the limit  to the following:

[DateColumn] > Date(2016,07,31) 
= no change

[DateColumn] > Date(2017,08,01) 
= the variance calculations start from the next period (ie: 01-Sep-16), with the same spike for the first month